# Четкость пикселей

Tags: unity3d

допустим у меня есть спрайт 32х32 пикселя, какие нужно сделать действия с настройками(конкретно) что бы получить результат, как в игре (Pixelforce 2)(Android) это просто как пример из тех на который я наткнулся, там пиксели при движении спрайта настолько это возмжожно - плавно переходят по игровому пространству прям кайф... У меня же что бы я не делал (добавлял pixel perfect camera, менял настройки камеры согласно PPU спрайта, изменял сетку), результат один - всеравно появляются дефекты в виде добавления/удаления саб пикселей, где-то больше где-то меньше. Или может тут без какого то супер ассета не обойтись подскажите плиз..

Answer (score 0):

В следующий раз постарайтесь писать вопрос грамотно и вежливо, пожалуйста.

Мой совет: Попробуйте нажать на нужную Вам текстуру (Texture2D) и в окне инспектора поменяйте значение поля "Filter Mode" на "Point(no filter)", как показано на скриншоте. Благодаря этому, Unity будет отрисовывать спрайт пиксель в пиксель.
[image: Inspector]

Comment: Извиняюсь если нагрубил вопросом. Спасибо за совет, но я это сделал сразу как импортировал спрайты в проект.

Answer (score -1):

Вот скриншот непосредственно с телефона, в первом варианте спрайт сместил на одну позицию сетки с зажатым контрлом, как результат с правой стороны спрайта появился дополнительный столб саб пикселей.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]